# How to add code for forgot/reset password using Parse Android Java

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-edittext, buttonclick, forgot-password

I am trying to set up a editText and Button to allow a user to reset their password via Parse. I've done some research and I keep coming back to the below example code out of the Parse docs. Am I supposed to replace "email@example.com" with a string made up of the current user? How is the best way to collect the current user and place in the parenthesis?

```
Parse.User.requestPasswordReset("email@example.com")
.then(() => {
  // Password reset request was sent successfully
}).catch((error) => {
  // Show the error message somewhere
  alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
});
```

I am trying capture the users email in an emailEditText and insert it into the reset method. I keep getting an error regarding the ParseUser line of code.  I would appreciate any help you can give, thanks.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.AdventureGuideV2.ForgotPasswordActivity.onClick(ForgotPasswordActivity.java:42)
```

The line(42) the line containing the ParuseUser statement in my code snipet below:

```
public class ForgotPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText emailEditText;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);
        setTitle("Forgot Password");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ParseUser.requestPasswordResetInBackground(emailEditText.getText().toString(), new RequestPasswordResetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null){
                    //send email
                }else {
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ForgotPasswordActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enteryouremail"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailEditText" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, you havent initialized your `EditText` properly, you missed the binding of it.

Try adding below code to your `onCreate()`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);
        emailEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);  //add here
        setTitle("Forgot Password");
    }
```

Comment: Yes @Blu , adding the findViewById within the onCreate took away the error. Thanks I should have caught that ...;-)

Comment: I have another question though, I am still not getting an email sent to email I input into the editText field. In addition to the first suggestion you had I have toggled the if (e == null) to if (e != null) and added some Log.i statements within the if statement. Here is my updated code:

Comment: public class ForgotPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText emailEditText;

    Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ParseUser.requestPasswordResetInBackground(emailEditText.getText().toString(), new RequestPasswordResetCallback() {

            Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {

Comment: if (e != null){
                //send email
                Log.i("Button", "Was clicked");
                Log.i("Email captured was", emailEditText.getText().toString());
                Log.i("Email was sent", "Successfully");
                }else {

                 }
            }
        });
    }

Comment: Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);
        emailEditText = findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
        setTitle("Forgot Password");
    }
}

Comment: I have tried to manually set the "email verified" field to true in Bitnami Parse API, but that does not seem to matter. any further thoughts?

Comment: I get a return of the email I enter in the Log.i statement and the email is the one I have already built previously in Bitnami Parse API.

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: Hi again...I am still not getting the reset email. Also I have a long delay after clicking my onClick method before it collects the email text and runs the intent taking me back to my mainActivity. Have I created some kind of loop? Are there some particular errors I should look for?

Comment: I realized I did not show you the intent code. It is located within the 'if' statement along with the Log.i statements, here is the code:

Comment: try {  if (e != null) { Log.i("Button", "Was clicked");
  Log.i("Email captured was", emailEditText.getText().toString());
                        Log.i("Email was sent", "Successfully");
                        Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, message + emailEditText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {  }
                } catch (Exception a) {
                    a.printStackTrace(); }}});

Comment: Do I need to use a email service such as MailGun to act as a backend server to accomplish this action?